# How do I pass inputs to cmd prompt after I have run the os.system command?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I am trying to start kafka producer via cmd prompt (I have kube installed in my local). This is the code that I am using :

`os.system('cmd /k "kubectl run kafka-producer152 -ti --image=strimzi/kafka:0.18.0-kafka-2.4.0  --rm=true --restart=Never -- bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 17.148.115.9:32033 --topic ship"')`

The topic is 'ship'.The command executes by running the producer command given above.

What should be done if I want the command to be executed (which it does now) and fetch all the data (inputs) from a file stored in same directory (values.txt) and enter those values only after executing the above kubectl command int the same cmd window.

Comment: A much better approach is to switch to a `subprocess`, like also ruggested in the `os.system()` documentation. Then you can include a directory to run in with `cwd`, and probably avoid `cmd` altogether. But if you `open` the file in Python first and connect it to the `stdin` of the subprocess, there is probably no need *per se* for the process to run in any particular directory, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Windows person (thank goodness) but I think the following should do what you are asking.

```py
import subprocess

with open(r'C:\razy\windows\path\values.txt') as values:
    subprocess.run(['kubectl', 'run', 'kafka-producer152',
            '-ti', '--image=strimzi/kafka:0.18.0-kafka-2.4.0',
            '--rm=true', '--restart=Never',
            '--', 'bin/kafka-console-producer.sh',
            '--broker-list', '17.148.115.9:32033',
            '--topic', 'ship'],
        stdin=values,
        # probably not
        #cwd=r'c:\razy\windows\path',
        # probably yes
        check=True, text=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!!
It worked. Had to remove the 't' from '--ti' because it was enabling the TTY interactive mode (my fault though).

Life saver!